# RUNTIME ERROR IN PUT REQUEST DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**I am trying to upload all user contacts to the server. Meaning if let's say a user registers on the app, the front-end takes all the phone contacts of the user and pushes it to the server so that it can be saved in database of the user.**

**models.py**

**Here in the user model, below you can see I put contact list as a Textfield, and I want to save only the giveName and phoneNumber of the user as a dictionary.**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    phone = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date_joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_signedup_user = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    otp = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')

    clubs_joined_by_user = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    number_of_clubs_joined = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    contact_list = models.TextField(default='')   #this is the contact_list field, where I want user's contact details
    total_frames_participation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    talked_to = models.CharField(max_length=1500,default='')


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'full_name']


#Since we created a manager for this Custom user model, which we use in the following way below.
    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**serializers file ---> I did use a google's (phonenumbers) library to parse the phonenumber to get country code and phone number. And also I am using a "PUT" request to put phone numbers into the user's contact list**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import User
import json
import phonenumbers
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # used for displaying list of users, with serializing the fields as written.

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','phone','full_name','id','clubs_joined_by_user','number_of_clubs_joined','contact_list','total_frames_participation')

class UserContactListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['contact_list','user','id']

    # def create(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    #     is_many = isinstance(request.data,list)
    #     if is_many:
    #         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,many=True)
    #         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    #         self.perform_create(serializer)
    #         headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    #         return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,headers=headers)



    def update(self, instance, validated_data,*args,**kwargs):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user',{})
        user = instance.user
        instance.contact_list = validated_data.get('contact_list',instance.contact_list)
        some_list = json.loads(instance.contact_list)
        final_list = []
        for i in range(len(some_list)):
            final_list.append({
                'name': some_list[i]["givenName"],
                'phone':some_list[i]["phoneNumbers"][0]["number"],
            })
        for j in range(len(final_list)):
            x = phonenumbers.parse(final_list[j]['phone'])
            final_list[j]['phone'] = '+' + f'{x.country_code}' + f'{x.national_number}'

        instance.contact_list = final_list
        instance.save(*args,**kwargs)
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class ContactListViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserContactListSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = []
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['id']


#I tried this below approach too of writing the above api view.

class ContactListAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self,request,user_id):
        try:
            desired_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            serializer = UserContactListSerializer(desired_user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def put(self,request,user_id):
        try:
            desired_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            serializer = UserContactListSerializer(desired_user,data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Below is the format in which I receive the data from iOS device(client-side) about user's contact list from which I only want givenName and only ONE phoneNumber**

```
[
  {
    "jobTitle": "Producer",
    "recordID": "177C371E-701D-42F8-A03B-C61CA31627F6",
    "postalAddresses": [
      {
        "state": "CA",
        "label": "work",
        "region": "CA",
        "postCode": "94010",
        "country": "",
        "city": "Hillsborough",
        "street": "165 Davis Street"
      }
    ],
    "company": "Creative Consulting",
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "label": "work",
        "email": "kate-bell@mac.com"
      }
    ],
    "urlAddresses": [
      {
        "label": "homepage",
        "url": "[www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com/)"
      }
    ],
    "imAddresses": [],
    "middleName": "",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "label": "mobile",
        "number": "(555) 564-8583"
      },
      {
        "label": "main",
        "number": "(415) 555-3695"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "Kate",
    "birthday": {
      "day": 20,
      "month": 0,
      "year": 1978
    },
    "hasThumbnail": false,
    "familyName": "Bell"
  },
  {
    "jobTitle": "",
    "recordID": "AB211C5F-9EC9-429F-9466-B9382FF61035",
    "postalAddresses": [
      {
        "state": "CA",
        "label": "home",
        "region": "CA",
        "postCode": "94925",
        "country": "USA",
        "city": "Corte Madera",
        "street": "332 Laguna Street"
      }
    ],
    "company": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "imAddresses": [],
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "label": "home",
        "number": "555-478-7672"
      },
      {
        "label": "mobile",
        "number": "(408) 555-5270"
      },
      {
        "label": "home fax",
        "number": "(408) 555-3514"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "Daniel",
    "urlAddresses": [],
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "label": "home",
        "email": "d-higgins@mac.com"
      }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": false,
    "familyName": "Higgins"
  },
  {
    "jobTitle": "",
    "recordID": "410FE041-5C4E-48DA-B4DE-04C15EA3DBAC",
    "postalAddresses": [
      {
        "state": "GA",
        "label": "work",
        "region": "GA",
        "postCode": "30303",
        "country": "USA",
        "city": "Atlanta",
        "street": "3494 Kuhl Avenue"
      },
      {
        "state": "GA",
        "label": "home",
        "region": "GA",
        "postCode": "30303",
        "country": "USA",
        "city": "Atlanta",
        "street": "1234 Laurel Street"
      }
    ],
    "company": "",
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "label": "work",
        "email": "John-Appleseed@mac.com"
      }
    ],
    "urlAddresses": [],
    "imAddresses": [],
    "middleName": "",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "label": "mobile",
        "number": "888-555-5512"
      },
      {
        "label": "home",
        "number": "888-555-1212"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "John",
    "birthday": {
      "day": 22,
      "month": 5,
      "year": 1980
    },
    "hasThumbnail": false,
    "familyName": "Appleseed"
  },
  {
    "jobTitle": "",
    "recordID": "F57C8277-585D-4327-88A6-B5689FF69DFE",
    "postalAddresses": [
      {
        "state": "CA",
        "label": "home",
        "region": "CA",
        "postCode": "94965",
        "country": "USA",
        "city": "Sausalito",
        "street": "1001 Leavenworth Street"
      }
    ],
    "company": "",
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "label": "home",
        "email": "anna-haro@mac.com"
      }
    ],
    "urlAddresses": [],
    "imAddresses": [],
    "middleName": "",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "label": "home",
        "number": "555-522-8243"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "Anna",
    "birthday": {
      "day": 29,
      "month": 7,
      "year": 1985
    },
    "hasThumbnail": false,
    "familyName": "Haro"
  }
]
```

**urls.py**

`router.register(r'post_contacts_to_server',views.ContactListViewset)`

**or If I use the Class based API View, then :**
 `path('post_contacts_to_server/<int:user_id>/',ContactListAPIView.as_view(),name='send_contacts_to_server'),`

**What and where do I modify code so it works**